# Facebook login button broke?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-social-plugins

I have a couple of facebook buttons and they appear as plain text. I have no clue why. It happened all of a sudden, I didn't change the code. All browsers show it as plain text.
My code is:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


 </script>
    <ul>
      <li><fb:login-button scope="user_map" id="get_map" onclick="self.location=http://localhost:8080/savefunctions.php?runFunction=getLikes">Get Map</fb:login-button></li>
      <li><fb:login-button scope="user_groups" id="get_acc" onclick="self.location=http://localhost:8080/savefunctions.php?runFunction=getLikes">Get your account info</fb:login-button>
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1">Gica</div></li>
      <li><fb:login-button scope="user_apps" id="like_acc" onclick="self.location=http://localhost:8080/savefunctions.php?runFunction=getLikes">Get apps</fb:login-button></li>
      <li><fb:login-button scope="user_groups" id="get_all"  onclick="http://localhost:8080/savefunctions.php?runFunction=getLikes">Get All</fb:login-button></li>
    </ul>
```

Please ignore things in `onClick`.
Please notice that I tried both `<fb:login-button>` and `<div class="fb-login-button">`. They both appear as plain text.

Comment: Check your browser’s JavaScript error console.

Comment: I did. No error is shown

Comment: Then show live site, please.

Comment: It's on a localhost, i'm developing an app

Comment: And your app settings are correct for that?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Anyway, as I said, I had no problem with it until today. And I did not change that file.
Also, the login button in my index.php is shown, so this is strange

Comment: You have to set the address you want logins to be possible from for your app.

Comment: Yes, I did set them. Might be from facebook, i'll try again later.
Yesterday worked with the very same code

Comment: Looks like you are initializing the SDK twice (by adding parameters after `#` on the script source), at least that should throw an error in console …

Comment: The console is clean, no errors or warnings are shown. I am using firebug

Comment: Lol thanks. It works without the parameters- which by the way still seems strange to me